# Bot Not responding in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a bot using the App studio and also tried adding a bot that already registered with Azure. I have also used the app id and the password with bot framework codes. I downloaded the manifest package from the app studio manifest section. The I used the custom upload option to upload the app. Now I tried a command from the bot but got no response. I am getting response from the "Test in web chat" section where I registered a channel for bot in Azure. Could anyone help us with this and explain where we are going wrong

Thank you

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added Teams as a channel for your bot? You could check this in the bot framework or azure portal where you have created the bot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1B5r.png

Comment: Gousia thanks a lot , Teams channel is added by default and I referred some forums and also tried added skype as a channel that too did not work. Is there anything that we are missing.

Comment: How are you running the app locally? Are you using NGROK for tunneling? Could you please check what is the error code you see on NGROK when you send a message?

Comment: Yes the app is running locally and I am not using NGROK, I am using a public url (https). I am getting response with the test in web chat but not when adding the app to teams

Comment: Could you please try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) for tunneling? Please follow the steps on how to [host app locally using ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#tunnel-using-ngrok).

Comment: Instead of public url we used ngrok and it worked thank you very much Gousia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to help but need more information. Where is the bot hosted? Is it running on your local computer? If so, are you tunnelling it to the outside world, using something like NGrok, so that Teams get's a "real" https address it can work with? If so, when you send the bot a message in Teams, do you at least see a record appearing in NGrok (so that you know it's reaching your workstation correctly)? Have you tried running Teams in the browser, instead of the desktop client, so that you can track network traffic using F12 tools? Have you opened the NGrok page (http://localhost:4040) to see incoming calls?

By the way, if you're using App Studio, you don't need to download the manifest and add it as a custom app - there's an option in App Studio called "Test and distribute" which will let you deploy the app directly.

Comment: Hilton thanks a lot. The bot is running in my local and I have a public url and it is a https. I am getting response when I try with the test option that is given azure portal. Below are the steps we followed
1) Logged into azure and registered a bot
2) Created an app with appstudio. Downloaded the package from test and distribute and uploaded using the upload custom app option. We were unable to install directly from appstudio since it said there is no permission. After adding the app we tried a command from the chat option and got no response. Please let us know what we are missing

Comment: We used NGROK instead of public url and it worked thank you Hilton

Comment: Ok thanks for the extra info. Recall what I said, you don't need to download the zip etc - you can deploy straight from within App Studio. If you're having trouble with that, it might be because your Teams Admininstrator has blocked "Sideloading" or "custom apps".

Comment: Aside from that, if the web chat is working, but Teams is not, it might be because your App ID and App Password are not specified properly in your Bot. But, first, make sure you're actually getting the call all the way to your local machine, from Teams. When you send a message to the Bot, in Teams, do you see anything appear in NGrok? NGrok will show you every time it receives a message. If NOT, it's probably something wrong with your Manifest in App Studio. If YES, it's probably something wrong on your bot itself. In App Studio, did you use the right App ID for your Bot?

Comment: Thanks for marking as answer, glad I could help. What was it in the end though, I'm curious to know?